# Билиотека для андроид

Tags: java, android, android-library

Только начал изучать андроид, хочу написать библиотеку для получения всех view на активности. Не могу нащупать точку входа. Какой объект нужно использовать, кроме view, разумеется? Как просканировать активность и получить id всех view?

Comment: LayoutInflater – это класс, который умеет из содержимого layout-файла создать View-элемент. Может в эту сторону стоит поковырять? 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` чтобы найти "root" `View` для `Activity`, дальше обойти всю иерархию, начиная с "root"-а, использую, к примеру, DFS:

```java
void traverse(View view) {
    // TODO: do what you need with the View

    // check if a ViewGroup, if so - traverse children
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        final int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int index = 0; index < childCount; index++) {
            final View child = viewGroup.childAt(index);
            traverse(child);
        }
    }
}
```